# jquery click button on another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onclick

I am trying to make a Google Chrome app that automatically opens a YouTube site and clicks on the expand button, or any button.
I tried to use the following JavaScript:

`$('#logo').click(); , .trigger('click');`

But nothing happens.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: your JavaScript won't work for cross domain iframe.

Comment: @K.K. he is building a "google chorme app" not a browser app, so there is no cross domain restriction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you're clicking must be clickable. There is a link around the logo (id="logo-container") you need to click that, not the logo itself. Right click on the logo in chrome, select inspect element and then you'll see what the <a> tag is around the img.

Try this:

```
$('#logo-container').click();
```

Comment: do you have jQuery in your page working? You can't use $() without it.

Comment: yes i have jQuery because i am doing an if($('#logo-container')) and it findes it and alerts me with "found"

Comment: no it is in another tab window.open(...) then windows.focus()

Comment: Just used my code in chrome console to click a link on youtube.com and it worked fine. Can you give me a specific link that doesn't work?

Comment: if ($('#logo-container')){
                   $('#logo-container').click();
                    alert("da");
               }